# Как передать данные из iframe в родительское окно - если у них разные домены?

Tags: javascript, html, https

Есть родительское окно:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Родитель</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://arxiv.mizar/mt4/data.html" style="height:110px" id="datafram" name="datafram">Пусто</iframe>
<div id=divka1 align="center"><table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="1">
  <tbody><tr bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="center"><td>Symbol</td><td>Period</td></tr>    
    <tr align="right"><td id="nam1">----</td><td id="dat1">---</td></tr>
  </tbody></table></div> 

<script>
document.getElementById('nam1').innerHTML=document.domain;
document.getElementById('dat1').innerHTML=document.getElementById('datafram').contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body').length;
  alert( iframeWindow.innerHTML); // true, окно из frames
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Есть фрейм datafram - и у них разные домены:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Фрейм</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id=fdiv1 align="center"><table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="1">
  <tbody><tr bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="center"><td>FSymbol</td><td>FPeriod</td></tr>    
    <tr align="right"><td id="fnam1">W</td><td id="fdat1">7</td></tr>
  </tbody></table></div> 
 <script>parent.handleMessage({txt:"W",time:7})</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Как передать с фрейма родителю..., или родителю посмотреть самому в фрейме, какие переменные там, и записать в другую табличку.
Я понимаю, что есть политика безопасности браузеров. Но знаю, что есть еще и здравый смысл, - тоесть надеюсь, что он есть в этой политеке... Ведь эти домены полностью мои. И этот обмен даными хочу зделать только в своем Firefox - браузере. То какая тут безопасность? Я что - буду сам себе вредить?

```
 P.S.: Вот, нашол такую статю: [Cross-domain Content Scripts][1] Только, чесно говоря, ничего не понял. Модули... Библиотеки... Да еще английский храмает. И, что бы фрейм обменивался даными, где найти в Firefox файл: package.json,  что бы туда впихнуть:
"permissions": {"cross-domain-content": ["http://site1.org/", "http://site2.com/"]}
```

???

Answer (score 2):

Политика безопасности работает и в отношении фреймов тоже. Нужно ставить разграничение при помощи `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://...`

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: А как правильно? Это, типа, на сервере в CORS on Apache, в директории прописать:  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"   ИЛИ как? И где?

Comment: К сожалению, по поводу апача я вам не подскажу

Comment: Нет. ( Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" ) - не помог.  Похоже он для GET, POST запросов...

Comment: Обновил про 
`X-Frame-Options`